# Failed to install mobz/elasticsearch-head, reason: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use -verbose to get detailed information

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Why do I get the following error when i try to install the *`elasticsearch` - head`* plugin through Command prompt?

```
C:\tomcat\webapps\elasticsearch-1.1.1\bin>plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

Error is :

```
    Installing mobz/elasticsearch-head...
    Trying https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/archive/master.zip...

   **Failed to install mobz/elasticsearch-head, reason:** failed to download out of all
    possible locations..., use -verbose to get detailed information
```

Comment: Check your user privileges. You have to run the command with administrator privileges I guess

Comment: If were a administrator, I am unable to start the Elasticsearch. the moment I click elasticsearch.bat, the cmd prmpt displays for a split of time and disappears. Can I have any solution for this.

Comment: Sorry I'm not a Windows expert but it seems that the problem is that you don't have enough user privileges to install the plugin

Comment: Could you please run the command with the -verbose option `plugin -verbose -install mobz/elasticsearch-head` and post the output, this might be helpful in finding a solution.

Comment: @PaigeCook, I think he is also running the wrong executable. Shouldn't he run plugin.bat since he's on Windows?

Comment: C:\tomcat\webapps\elasticsearch-1.1.1\bin>`plugin -verbose -install mobz/elastics
earch-head`
-> Installing mobz/elasticsearch-head...
Trying https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/archive/master.zip...
`Failed: SocketTimeoutException[connect timed out]`
Failed to install mobz/elasticsearch-head, reason: failed to download out of all
 possible locations..., use -verbose to get detailed information

Comment: Plugin.bat fails to run, so i am trying in command prompt.

Comment: you say fails to run, what do you mean by fails to run?

Comment: I actually use ES on a Windows Server platform, and I have Elasticsearch Head running on it too. What I have to do is this, in Powershell, `cd C:\elasticsearch-1.1.0\bin` I then do `.\plugin.bat --install mobz/elasticsearch-head` and that works fine for me every time.

Comment: @Garry I did in the same way, I am getting the error which i mentioned above. The .bat file is opening in command prompt for a fraction of second and it closes so i mentioned as it fails to run. What may be the reason for this. I am new to elasticsearch, can you help me out in this.Please.

Comment: Are you running powershell as an administrator?

Comment: No I am not running powershell

Answer (score 3):

Download it manually from https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head and unzip it in elasticsearch-1.4.2/plugins/head/_site/

and start elasticsearch server
then check in browser 
http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/

Answer (score 3):

I installed it successfully in this way:

```
bin/plugin -DproxyPort=port_number -DproxyHost=hostname -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

Replace the port_number and hostname in above command.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that head plugin installer is broken. It reports:

```
Can't get https://github.com/movz/elasticsearch-head/archive/master.zip
```

And when you try to download this file by hand, you will realize that installer can't work.

However you can use head plugin easily if you download it as zip from https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head, and then you just open index.html in your browser.